# Wordpress admin toolbar not loading styles after migration

Tags: admin, migration, css

I am really stumped by this one, have looked at various solutions online but nothing seems to work and I have the feeling I am missing something very basic.

Essentially, I used manageWP to clone my site to a new server, everything works great except the frontend admin bar/toolbar does not load any css styles (shows up as a simple list at the bottom fo the page). The ID #wpadminbar does not appear link to the relevant css file. Again, this is the only such issue and it is not related to plugins and themes as the problem persists even when changing themes or deactivating all plugins.

The only thing I can think of is that since the source wordpress installation was setup as subfolder (like so http://mymaindomain.com/newsite) and the new one is on the domain root (like so http://newsite.com) that there is some relative path somewhere that isn't working properly, but I have no idea where to even look or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you move a Wordpress install, you need to also edit two fields in the database. Run this against your database in order to find the values that need to be edited:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE option_name IN('siteurl', 'home');
```

If database access is not an option, another way to do this is by editing your wp-config.php file to include the following two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com');
```

Straight from http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

> 1. The "Home" setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.
> 2. The "Site URL" setting is the address where your WordPress core files reside.